# Error Unknown type "webform__webform" using gatsby-drupal-webform & GraphQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drupal, graphql, gatsby

I get this error when using gatsby-drupal-webform in my Gatsby js site :

```
Failed to compile
GraphQL Error Unknown type "webform__webform". Did you mean "date_format__date_format"?

  file: C:/xampp/htdocs/drupal-gatsby-t/node_modules/gatsby-drupal-webform/dist/Webform.jsx

   1 | 
>  2 |  fragment Webform on webform__webform {
     |                      ^
   3 |      name: drupal_internal__id
   4 |      description
   5 |      status
   6 |      elements {
   7 |          name
   8 |          _type
   9 |          _title
  10 |          _title_display
  11 |          _default_value
  12 |          _description
```

Comment: I edited the question for readability, but more information is needed like what do you want to achieve ? what did you tried ?

Comment: Hey @EricLavault I am building a Drupal 8 site fully decoupled using Gatsby (React). The website needs a form. I will use the webform drupal module for this and then get the webform query with graphql to use it with gatsby-drupal-webform plugin

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the module. The version of the package used in this question is old and it didn't work without my Drupal hacks that were not published at the time.

I would suggest updating to newest version by running `npm install gatsby-drupal-webform@latest --save`

Then you also need to:

- Install a [Drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/react_webform_backend) from the Drupal repository. This module will preprocess Webform jsonapi output and open a REST endpoint that is used to submit forms.
- Have Gatsby access Drupal jsonapi with `access any webform configuration` permission. This can be done by installing `basic_auth` module for Drupal and [setting username and password](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-drupal/#basic-auth) of a user with that permission in `gatsby-source-drupal` settings.

You can take a look at [this example](https://github.com/oikeuttaelaimille/gatsby-drupal-webform/blob/master/examples/gatsby-webforms/src/templates/form.jsx) project.